# On which column should I create FK constraint for this table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I've been preparing for the SQL Server cetification 70-461. I can't understand why the correct answer on question below is C. The Great appropriate for any suggestions.
Question:
[image]

> Unless stated above, no columns in the Employee table reference other
>   tables. Confidential information about the employees is stored in a
>   separate table named EmployeeData. One record exists within
>   EmployeeData for each record in the Employee table. You need to assign
>   the appropriate constraints and table properties to ensure data
>   integrity and visibility. On which column in the Employee table should you >create a Foreign Key constraint that references a different table in the >database?

- A. DateHired
- B. DepartmentID
- C. EmployeeID
- D. EmployeeNum
- E. FirstName

Comment: If the question is correctly presented here, the answer is **not** C, and I don't understand how there are now 3 answers stating that it is.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever It seems to me the same =(

Answer (score 0):

In the context of relational databases, a foreign key is a field (or collection of fields) in one table that uniquely identifies a row of another table (sometimes even the same table).

In simpler words, the foreign key is defined in a second table, but it refers to the primary key or a unique key in the first table.

For example, this table called Employees has a primary key called employee_id. Another table called Employee Details has a foreign key which references employee_id in order to uniquely identify the relationship between the two tables.

Only a primary key of a table can be a foreign key in another table.

Answer (score 0):

It should be C because:

- EmployeeID is unique for each employee record in the table.
- Is used by other tables in the database to relate data with the employee. This means that EmpoyeeID value could be used to create foreign keys referencing to the Employee table.
- EmployeeNum is also unique but it's alphanumeric field which probably consumes more space than EmployeeID.
- EmployeeNum exists only in Employee table that's why it's not a good candidate for PK.

Answer (score 0):

**Only Possible answer is C**.
*Because*,

1. EmployeeID, it self it is Primary key for the table. as there has mentioned two things i).Uniquely defined each record, ii).Throughout the database all other tables this column is the reference. Hence this is PK for self table.
2. EmployeeNum is the Information Column of same table. which refers to Column EmployeeId (self table).
3. ReportsToId is the column which Only Refers to EmployeeId (kind of self joined key)
4. *DepartmentId, is the Only column which has the information of some other table. And also it has mentioned that it refers to Other table*.

So only possible answer is "**C**".

Table definition must be something like this:

[image]